# Autohotkey script to change Throttlestop 8.60 profiles

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Is it possible to make a script, that would switch profiles in Throttlestop 8.60? Built-in hotkeys are restricted to ctrl-alt-shift + number, i want to bind it to "Win+Ctrl+1" for profile #1 and "Win+Ctrl+2" for profile 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoHotkey should allow you to do that simply by assigning your desired shortcut key to the pre-existing key the program accepts already.

For example, the main code in the script could use hotkey assignments looking something like this:

```
#IfWinActive, Throttlestop     ; Make this match the WinTitle as needed--see AHK docs

#^2::                   ; Win+Ctrl+2
    SendInput, ^!+2     ; Ctrl+Alt+Shift+2
Return

^!+2::Return            ; Turn off App's default hotkey combo (return without action)

#IfWinActive            ; Allow subsequent hotkeys to be global
```

After downloading AutoHotkey you could modify the default script and then run it-- it will have an 'H' icon in the system tray after starting it up.

Comment: Thanks, my original app's hotkeys must be active in order to work, but is it possible to turn off app's default hotkeys with autohotkey?

Comment: Just add another hotkey of that definition and return with no action. See updated post.  SendInput won't trigger this new hotkey since it obeys a SendLevel that will exclude it by default (so one hotkey can send those keys, and another can exclude them from the app).

Comment: Order is important? If i place that blank return above - then it wouldn't work, right?

Comment: Order is not important. They are two different hotkeys and can be listed in any order.